# Issue with Hibernate Named Queries Compilation

Tags: hibernate

Is there any way I can avoid Hibernate Named Queries compilation and validation during server boot-up?

Comment: You could not use named queries.

Comment: I want them in hbm.xml but not precompiled while booting up my tomcat.